# Login credentials showing in url parameters in react js

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am a beginner in React JS, I created a login form and after click on login button then **username and password is showing in the URL**. I don't want to show this in URL. How to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
<form className="loginform" onSubmit={this.ValidateUser}>
  <input
    className="form-control"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Email"
    name="email"
    autocomplete="off"
    value={this.state.email}
    onChange={(e) => this.changeEmailHandler(e.target.value)}
  />
  <input
    className="form-control"
    type="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    name="password"
    value={this.state.password}
    onChange={(e) => this.changePasswordHandler(e.target.value)}
  />
  <input
    type="submit"
    id="kt_login_signin_submit"
    className="btn btn-brand"
    value="Sign In"
  />
</form>
```

Comment: include `e.preventDefault()` at the first line in `this.ValidateUser`?

Comment: if you still facing problem than please provide validateUser function code .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `e.preventDefault()` in `ValidateUser` method should do the trick.

#### Edit-01:

already pointed out in the comments.